# Rails Resque Concurrency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

My application is processing jobs with `Resque.enqueue`

I am starting the worker with `rake resque:work QUEUE='converter'`

To my understanding, in order to start 2 workers to process 2 requests for the same queue concurrently, I can start another worker with `rake resque:work QUEUE='converter'` in another terminal.

Is there a simple option to start 2 workers to work concurrently on the same queue without using the resque-pool gem, and without having to type in `rake resque:work QUEUE='converter'` twice?

Comment: Missed that in the docs and it's hard to find that on a search engine. Can we make it an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [specify the worker count when running the command](https://github.com/resque/resque#running-multiple-workers), like so:

`$ COUNT=2 QUEUE='converter' rake resque:workers`

Answer (score 1):

It's advised within the same Resque codebase to only use `COUNT=2` while on development environment. To manage more than one Resque worker, you'd need something like https://github.com/nevans/resque-pool